# cost optimization for Azure cognitive search service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Need to optimize cost for Azure cognitive search service, the plan we choose for this service is standard3 High density which is some what expensive (1000-indexes, 0-indexers, 200GB/partition, 36-Search units, 13-Replicas, 3-Partions).

1)In the Azure cognitive search service overview tab, I can see Replicas-1, Partions-1 and Search Units-1, based on this data can we decide if we can downgrade the plan ?

2)How / where can I view the usage in Azure Portal -  to check last few months of Azure cognitive search service data and see if we are utilizing this service properly or not ?. So basically based on this data I want to downgrade the plan.

3)In the azure cognitive search service, is it possible can we downgrade / upgrade the pricing tiers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)In the Azure cognitive search service overview tab, I can see
> Replicas-1, Partions-1 and Search Units-1, based on this data can we
> decide if we can downgrade the plan ?

You actually need to check:

- number of indexes
- used storage
- number of successful requests / number of failed requests

> 2)How / where can I view the usage in Azure Portal - to check last few
> months of Azure cognitive search service data and see if we are
> utilizing this service properly or not ?. So basically based on this
> data I want to downgrade the plan.

Azure Monitor

> 3)In the azure cognitive search service, is it possible can we
> downgrade / upgrade the pricing tiers ?

Because you have multiple partitions, I don't think so as data won't be migrated from one partition to another (once you downgrade). You'd better create a new Azure AI Search (Azure Cognitive Search got rebranded), then add your indexes and data, then redirect traffic to the new instance.

Comment: Custodia Thank you. In Azure Monitor - Metrics , I can see doc processed count, search latency, search queries per second, throttled search queries percentage. I do not find used storage , where should I find this data ?

Comment: it should be in Azure Ai Search overview page